# Why does the pseudo element vibrate when width:fit-content is added?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    :root{
    --maincolor:#000099;
}
    .banner{
    transform: translateX(-250px);
    transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
    animation-name: slide-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: fit-content;
}

.banner:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
.banner:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(-250px);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(1px);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
.container-content{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 200px 40px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.container-content h1{
    color: var(--primarycolor);
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.container-content #span2{
    color: var(--maincolor);
}
.banner-animate1::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: slide-in-animate1;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
.banner-animate2::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: slide-in-animate2;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
.banner-animate3::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: slide-in-animate2;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
@keyframes slide-in-animate1 {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }
}
@keyframes slide-in-animate2 {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
@keyframes slide-in-animate3 {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container-content">
        <h1 class="banner banner-animate1 " >hello,</h1>
        <h1 class="banner banner-animate2" >my name is</h1>
        <h1 class="banner banner-animate3" >angelo</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, If you run this code, you'd notice that at the end of the pseudo element transitioning over its main element, It vibrates before it ends, please I need some help.
As the pseudo element moves across its element, It vibrates before being hidden.
The width:fit-content; and the overflow:hidden; given to the class banner is what makes the pseudo element hide while transitioning away from its main element, Please I want the pseudo element to transition in and out smoothly without breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think because the text contains spaces it updates weird. Anyway if you use `width: max-content;` in the banner class it won't vibrate weird and the width is still contained to only the text. This only works because the element only contains text if you put other divs inside you might need `width: fit-content;`

Comment: i't still vibrates